# docusign connect for salesforce on 30-day trial orgs

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have a Trialforce Source ORG on which I installed Docusign for Salesforce. I want to display the Docusign status on a page layout driven by my custom object. From my Docusign.net account, I set up the connection to this Salesforce TSO ORG. Works well, no issues with it.

The purpose of this TSO ORG is to spin off 30-day trial orgs from it. The salesforce user ID on these spin off ORGs cannot be the same as TSO's. Hence, the Docusign status on this spin off ORG's page layout doesn't get updated.

The reason might be here: 
DocuSign Connect Settings > DocuSign Connect for Salesforce->Salesforce Account Settings.

This setting page allows only one login for salesforce configuration. Any idea how I can be:
"Using with One Docusign Account and with multiple Docusign Users, I can connect to multiple Salesforce Instances?"

Answer (score 0):

At this time, it is possible to only have 1 Salesforce Connect configuration in a DocuSign account.